# Laravel 5.1 Namespace for Controller give Reflection Exception

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, composer-php, laravel-5.1

Good Afternoon, I don´t understand this exception

> ReflectionException in Container.php line 737: Class app\Http\Controllers\Login\LoginController does not exist

I know thats is related with the namespace but i configured my composer.json autoload. When i changed it to app\Http\Controllers\Login it works ok.
I also did artisan clear-compiled and composer dump-autoload

My Class is like this

```
<?php

namespace Login;

use Controller;
use Validator;
use Input;
use Auth;
use Redirect;
use View;

class LoginController extends Controller{}
```

My composer.json autoload

```
"autoload": {
 "classmap": 
  [ "app/Http/Controllers" , "app/Models" , "database" ],
 "psr-4": {
  "app\\": "app/" 
 }
},
```

My Controllers Directory is like this

```
- app
-- Http
--- Controllers
---- Login
----- LoginController.php
-- Models
--- User
---- User.php
```

Thanks in advance

Edit: Why i don't have problems with my model files when i use a namespace like this:

> namespace User;

In my config auth i have this:

> 'model' => User\User:class,

Answer (score 2):

Your controller is in **Login** namespace, while it should be in **app\Http\Controllers\Login** namespace.

No entries in composer.json can change the way PHP's namespaces work - the mapping in there can just be used to tell autoloader where to look for physical files from given namespace.

Comment: When i used laravel 4 i didn't need to put app/models or app/controllers , i thought that with the classmap change it would work.

Comment: classmap attribute in composer.json is there to tell autoloader where to find classes that don't follow PSR-0 or PSR-4 convention. Neither composer or autoloader can change the fact, that your controller is in "Login" namespace

Comment: Avoid using the classmap feature if your code can conform to PSR-4. It will hide errors with classes incorrectly named or placed in the file system, and it will take more time to create the autoloader because the directory tree has to be scanned for php files and parsed for classes.

Comment: Thanks Sven i only need that answer. i will use the default configuration of the autoloader.